# how to fill the data into spinner from textfile in android

Tags: android, web-services, spinner

I am working on android offline data management.  I am creating a text file where all the data of the main server will be store and after that I read it.

How can I fill textfile to a `Spinner`?

Comment: How you put your data in the text file and in what format it will be shown?each line?each word?what you tried?

Comment: fetch data from main server through webservice as string form, It is read line by line And return As string

Comment: You may show the contents of the file and then what you want to show from the file to spinner

Comment: It is created automatically I am reading it through Buffer reader Line by line and my Spinner for all location

Comment: means I have  a web method like getlocation I m retriving it into the text file and then I want to save it into the spinner (Location is like Mumbai.Noida Etc)

Comment: simple, First Store data into array from the database and then set array to that spinner

Answer (score 0):

```
        String[] str = new String[totalLine];


BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("in.txt"));

String line = in.readLine();
int index=0;
while(line!=null)
{

str[index++]=line;   
line = in.readLine();
}

 spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, str);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Edit:**

From your previous comment what i got is your data is in Mumbar.Noida format

Do this

```
 String[] str = response.toString().split(","); 

     spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, str);

            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

this will populate spinner like

```
Mumbai
Noida
```